# how to insert a string as date with 106 format in mssql database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, insert

I need to insert a string as date into my `MSSQL` database.
I am trying this query but it is not inserting as per my expectation.

```
Insert into date_table (CONFIG_DATE) 
Values (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),CONVERT(DATETIME,'18-SEP-13',103),106));
```

Inserted as : ***2013-09-18***
but expected output is **18-SEP-2013**

Any help would be appreciated on this..

Comment: If you're storing this in a `datetime` (or `date`, `datetime2`, etc) column, then they don't **have** a format. What you're seeing is the default formatting that the *client* tools apply when selecting the value back out because they have to turn it into a string for display.

Comment: What are you expecting by inserting data value in this format? Can't you use the formatting when you select this value?

Comment: Never perform such conversions on the DB side but on the client side. Display of values it not a concern of the database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not wure what you expecting by inserting date value in this format since I can't see any advantage or posibility of that.

I think the best way is to store the value in `date` or `datatime` format in database and apply the formatting when you do the select.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you converting converted date back to a string before inserting. `Date itself does not have a format`. Formatting is used for presentation purposes.

Best thing is to **store date as a Date not a string**. First conversion should be fine with 106 style.

```
Insert into date_table (CONFIG_DATE) 
Values (CONVERT(DATETIME,'18-SEP-13',106));
```

When converting strings to date type, safest practice is to use culture independent ISO formats. For example `yyyymmdd` (ISO format) and `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm (no spaces)` (ISO8601).

Answer (score 0):

can you please provide your table schema ??

i think your column datatype is datetime, date or datetime2 and you cant insert **18-SEP-2013** in **datetime ,date or datetime2** columns .. you need to insert it **2013-09-18** but when you selecting it at that time you can write

```
select CONVERT(varchar(30), CONFIG_DATE, 106)
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Insert into date_table (CONFIG_DATE) 
Values (replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),CONVERT(DATETIME,'18-SEP-13',103),106),' ','-'))
```

Comment: why are you converting it twice ..??

Comment: @Dhaval you should ask this to who asked this question. and i would suggest you thatyou should not **-1** to right answer (as per asker's need).